# why is race condition in following code

Tags: c, race-condition

Why does the following code have a race condition?

```
static int i=0;
void some_fun()
{
  ++i;
  if(2==i)
  {
    printf("some message");
  }
}
```

Comment: There is not a race condition in the code given. It is not multi-threaded for a start.

Comment: Paste code where you invoke some_fun() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is called from multiple threads, the static variable i needs to be protected.
This can be done with a lock as mentioned before, or in this case using an atomic increment operation which is more efficient.
If you are using the gcc compiler it would look something like this:

```
static int i=0;
void some_fun()
{
  int local_i = __sync_add_and_fetch(&i, 1);
  if(2==local_i)
  {
    printf("some message");
  }
}
```

The __sync_add_and_fetch() function adds the second param to the first and returns the sum. All this in as an atomic operation. This is more efficient than grabbing and releasing a lock

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this function is called from multiple threads, it has an race condition because the variable `i` has a static storage duration and it is shared between all the threads, so multiple threads can race amongst themselves to modify this variable.

The problem is one same variable being shared across multiple threads unlike the local/auto variables which are one per thread.

If you want to avoid the race condition you need to synchronize the access to this shared variable by using synchronization constructs, the simplest and most relevant here being an mutex.

Answer (score 0):

`Race condition` occurs when multiple threads or processes access share resource at the same time.

And in your code, shared resource is i variable. And often, we call it `critical section`.

So, if this code is access by multiple threads or processes at same time, and modified it.For example, they one increase and one decrease it. So, the data won't be consistent.

Hope this help :)